# Split $C[0,1]$ into direct sum of two infinite-dimensional subspaces

Tags: functional-analysis

How to split $C[0,1]$ in the form of a direct sum of two infinite-dimensional subspaces?

Comment: $C[0,1] \subset C[0, 1/2] \oplus C[1/2,1]$?

Comment: @user8469759 Surely that would only produce continuous functions $f$ such that $f(1/2) = 0$?

Comment: I don't see why... there's no restriction to $f(1/2)$ to be $0$, but you can embed $C[0,1]$ in the direct sum I mentioned. Unless the OP meant equality necessarily

Comment: @user8469759 The way I interpreted your comment was that $C[0, 1/2]$ was the set of continuous functions on $[0, 1]$ that were $0$ on $(1/2, 1]$, and similarly for $C[1/2, 1]$. The OP seemed to want $C[0, 1]$ to be written as the direct sum of two of its infinite-dimensional subspaces.

Comment: No I meant continuous function in that interval, constant functions fit that description.

Comment: @user8469759 Then neither of them are subspaces of $C[0, 1]$.

Comment: I see my mistake. How about this. Pick any $f \in C[0,1]$ then $f = g + h$ where $g, h \in C[0,1]$ such that $g(0) = h(1) = 0$?

Comment: @user8469759 The sum would not be direct: there'd be infinitely many ways to produce each vector. I just wrote an answer that adapted your first idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more concrete decomposition. For every continuous function $f$ of $[0,1]$ let $f^*$ be the function $f(x)+f(1-x)$ and $f^{**}$ be the function $f(x)-f(1-x)$. Both sets of finctions $f^*$ and $f^{**}$ are infinite dimensional subspaces, they intersect by the space consisting of one function and their sum is the whole space of continuous functions on the unit interval.

Comment: I like this one, you're like decomposing a $f \in C[0,1]$ in odd and even part w.r.t. $1/2$.

Comment: That is true, these are the odd and even parts.

Answer (score 2):

Take a basis of your space, divide it into two infinite parts. The first part spans the first direct summand and the second part spans the second summand.

Comment: (the +1 was from me) This answer is described with 3 letters: LOL

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by user8469759's comments, let
\begin{align*}
A &= \{f \in C[0, 1] : f \text{ is constant on }[1/2, 1]\} \\
B &= \{f \in C[0, 1] : f \text{ is } 0 \text{ on }[0, 1/2]\}.
\end{align*}
Then $A$ and $B$ are infinite-dimensional and $C[0, 1] = A \oplus B$.

EDIT: Indeed, this idea would work for decomposing into finitely many infinite-dimensional subspaces. Fix $n \in \Bbb{N}$ and suppose $1 < i < n$. We could then define
$$A_i = \left\{f \in C[0, 1] : f|_{[0, (i - 1)/n]} \equiv 0 \text{ and }f|_{[i/n, 1]} \text{ is constant}\right\},$$
as well as
\begin{align*}
A_1 &= \left\{f \in C[0, 1] : f|_{[1/n, 1]} \text{ is constant}\right\} \\
A_n &= \left\{f \in C[0, 1] : f|_{[0, (n-1)/n]} \equiv 0\right\}.
\end{align*}
Then $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ are infinite-dimensional, and $A_1 \oplus \ldots \oplus A_n = C[0, 1]$.

Comment: @JCAA I think you do get $x^2$. You would write it as a sum of$$\begin{align*}a(x) &= \begin{cases} x^2 & \text{if } 0 \le x \le 1/2 \\ 1/4 & \text{if } 1/2 < x \le 1 \end{cases} \in A \\ b(x) &= \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } 0 \le x \le 1/2 \\ x^2 - 1/4 & \text{if } 1/2 < x \le 1 \end{cases} \in B.\end{align*}$$Can you see anything wrong with this?

Comment: You are right. I did not look carefully at  your definition of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @JCAA Was it you who down-voted?

Comment: I do not think so.

Comment: @JCAA Hm, that's a pity.

Comment: Your $A$, $B$ work for $C[0,1]$ but not for $C^n$ for any $n>0$.

Comment: @JCAA True, but one could modify this example to accommodate. Instead of a constant function on the right half-interval for functions in $A$, one could simply force the function to be the $n$th degree Taylor polynomial to $A$ at $1/2$ on the right half-interval. Then you would get such a decomposition for $C^n[0, 1]$.

Comment: Of course a decomposition exists for every $n$ . According to your idea, it is going  to be different for every $n$. It does not need to the case.

Comment: @JCAA I'm not really sure what you're driving at here...

Comment: I am "driving at" the fact that your decomposition for every $n$ does work, but depends on $n$ which is not so for my answer or for the decomposition "the space of constants"+"the space of all functions with integral 0". However smooth (or even analytic) a function is the components will be smooth of the same degree or more.

Comment: @JCAA OK, fair enough. I just thought there might be some reason you were bringing up $C^n$/some motivation for constructing a decomposition into subspaces that you could intersect with $C^n[0, 1]$, etc, etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110018/discussion-between-jcaa-and-user803264).